# is this translation in Chinese of grammatical quality and flow?

Tags: translation

I am using a 3rd party translation company called Gengo to translate phrases and am trying to measure their ability to translate a phrase in English to Chinese, where flow and native quality are the most important.

Given the sentence:

> Getting information in my own language is more important than the
>   price of the product.

Is this translation of high quality in terms of grammar structure?

> 透過我自己的語言取得資訊比產品的價格還重要。

Comment: compare to Google Translate result:  "以我自己的語言獲取信息比產品的價格更重要.  "there's not much different. Both results seem acceptable but not quite reaching human editor level yet. Why not run a list of phrases of different degree of complexity, so we can compare Gengo and Google more accurately?

Comment: I think the original sentence is ambiguous. Interpretation 1: I use my language to communicate, and I get the information (in any language). Interpretation 2: I get the information by any means, and the information is in my language.

Comment: It depends on who are the readers. The translation company gives you the one more native to Taiwanese rather than Chinese.

Comment: potential confusion .... it may be mistaken as "透過我自己的語言取得資訊, 比透過我自己的語言取得產品的價格還重要."

Answer (score 1):

Talking about grammar, this version is perfectly fine. The problem is the word choice.

As a native speaker, my translation would be "通过母语获取信息比产品价格更重要".

Comment: potential confusion .... it may be taken as "通过母语获取信息, 比通过母语获取产品价格更重要".